Attaching Eraser To Pencil Smoothly
I'm trying to smoothly transition together two models—one with six sides and another with a smooth cylinder.

The problem with just over lapping them on each other I get this:

Would somebody know how I could do this properly?



In my example I started with a 18 vertices circle, extruded down for the cylidrical zone, extruded up.
Then I selected 12 vertices one by one and moved them along their edges, pressing G,G, 0.95, Enter, in order to have a regular constant beveling.


When I do this I get sharp edges where the mesh starts to transition.

In my example I have set Shade Smooth (right click > Shade smooth), and a SubSurf Modifier on. Then it relates to the distance between the regular circle and the beveled 6 sides one.

@CowToesies One question: do you want to get a smooth transition like shown here or is your goal to model a somewhat realistic pencil? Because this smooth transition is not how pencils are made.
